# admin-on-rest set up project in IDE's

Tags: javascript, ide, admin-on-rest

After reading guide I had been configure app, but IDE's (IDEA based like WebStorm/PHPStorm and VSCode) can't resolve imports from admin-on-rest, but react imports works well. WebStorm says `Cannot resolve symbol %component_name%`

So what I should set up to get full IDE autocompletion?

Comment: Depends. Auto-complete in dynamic languages is hard; it depends a lot on how things are exported and how much can be inferred by walking the code's AST.

Comment: aor uses an index file to make named exports from the module. Maybe you need to give the full path to it to be able to import. Check the file path of index.js in every folder of the aor node module.

Comment: still no fix for this